# validation for single # only in Pattern.compile

Tags: java, validation

i am using Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9 #/-]*$"); for validations. It allows more than one #, how can i restrict user to enter more than one #?

Answer (score 0):

The absolute simplest way is just to check, separately, the number of times `#` appears in the string.

Comment: is there any way with pattern.compile?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Matt that the count `#` is the simplest way. Anyway I provide another solution using regular expression.

**Note:** I am not sure that I properly understood your question, but I guess, that you want to modify your RegEx to allow one or none `#`.

`Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9 /-]*#?[a-zA-Z0-9 /-]*$")`

**Explanation:** It allows any character defined in the first group. There is unlimited amount of them. After that there can be at most one `#` character and after it again unlimited amount of non `#` symbols.